# need to convert the query result as json using json encode

Tags: php, json

I have an array as the result of a query. i need to convert into `json` using `json_encode`.    `print_r($data['products']);` array is as follows. I have used      `$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));` to output this array as `json`. But showing `SyntaxError: JSON.parse`: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the `JSON` data. Please help to make this as `json` and how can i fetch each thump on an another page once i call a API to this.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [thumb] => https://akkk.akk.com/store/image/cache/catalog/SRIRACHAMANGOBALSAMIC_FINAL_2x3-280x370.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [thumb] => https://akk.akk.com/store/image/cache/catalog/BLACKCHERRYBALSAMIC_FINAL-280x370.jpg ) [2] => Array ( [thumb] => https://akk.akk.com/store/image/cache/catalog/BLACKCURRANTBALSAMIC_FINAL-280x370.jpg ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the array values ​​with Comma(,)  and put the string values ​​between '' , And define array keys as string (You Cant Use Array value As a Key) Change :

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    ['thumb'] => 'https://akkk.akk.com/store/image/cache/catalog/SRIRACHAMANGOBALSAMIC_FINAL_2x3-280x370.jpg' ),
[1] => Array ( ['thumb'] => 'https://akk.akk.com/store/image/cache/catalog/BLACKCHERRYBALSAMIC_FINAL-280x370.jpg' ) ,
[2] => Array ( ['thumb'] => 'https://akk.akk.com/store/image/cache/catalog/BLACKCURRANTBALSAMIC_FINAL-280x370.jpg '))
```

To:

```
$thumbs =   Array ( 
0 => Array ( 
    'thumb' => 'https://akkk.akk.com/store/image/cache/catalog/SRIRACHAMANGOBALSAMIC_FINAL_2x3-280x370.jpg' ),
1 => Array ( 'thumb' => 'https://akk.akk.com/store/image/cache/catalog/BLACKCHERRYBALSAMIC_FINAL-280x370.jpg' ) ,
2 => Array ( 'thumb' => 'https://akk.akk.com/store/image/cache/catalog/BLACKCURRANTBALSAMIC_FINAL-280x370.jpg ')
```

)

> and encode thumbs as json data

in Other page :

```
$result= json_decode(api_result);
foreach ($result_array as $key => $value) {
    $thumb = $value['thumb'];//
}
```

Comment: but i have got that result as a query  result. Then how can i add , and ' ' to that